# Check Scores in Android Studio

Tags: android

This is my Code. When the user enters their answer and press the Submit Button which is the `AnswerCheck` Method, i would like the score to be shown in a `TextView` for example - if they input the right answer, the `TextView` would state 1 correct out of 1. I would like some help, Thanks

```
public class Perimeter extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int number;
    private int number2;
    private String myString;
    private String myString2;
    private int perimeter;
    private Random rand;
    private Random rand2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perimeter);

        rand = new Random();
        rand2 = new Random();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void PerimeterGame(View view) {
        number = rand.nextInt(12) + 1;
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rand1);
        myString = String.valueOf(number);
        myText.setText(myString);

        number2 = rand2.nextInt(12) + 1;
        TextView myText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rand2);
        myString2 = String.valueOf(number2);
        myText2.setText(myString2);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.question)).setText
        ("Find the perimeter of a rectange with a width of " + myString + "cm" + " and " + "length of " + myString2 + "cm" + ".");
    }

    public void AnswerCheck(View view) {
        EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answertext);
        int val = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());

        perimeter = (number + number2 + number + number2);
        if (val == perimeter) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The answer is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The answer is incorrect ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        findViewById(R.id.showsolbutton).setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you try so far? what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I honestly have no clue, how to do it

Comment: Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Have you looked at the answer I provided? If it's helpful, vote up.

Comment: i'm looking at it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set two global `int` variables

`private int totalQuestion = 0;`

and `private int correctQuestions = 0;`

Inside `public void PerimeterGame(View view)` increment `totalQuestion` by one.

When the answer is correct, inside `public void AnswerCheck(View view)` increment `correctQuestion` by one.

Finally, display the text

`youTextView.setText(String.valueOf(correctQuestions) + " correct out of " + String.valueOf(totalQuestion));`

Hope it helps.

```
public class Perimeter extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Code ommitted

    private int totalQuestion = 0 ;
    private int correctQuestions = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Code ommitted
    }

    public void PerimeterGame(View view) {

        // Increment totalQuestion
        totalQuestion++;
        number = rand.nextInt(12) + 1;
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rand1);
        myString = String.valueOf(number);
        myText.setText(myString);

        number2 = rand2.nextInt(12) + 1;
        TextView myText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rand2);
        myString2 = String.valueOf(number2);
        myText2.setText(myString2);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.question)).setText
        ("Find the perimeter of a rectange with a width of " + myString + "cm" + " and " + "length of " + myString2 + "cm" + ".");
    }

    public void AnswerCheck(View view) {
        EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answertext);
        int val = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());

        perimeter = (number + number2 + number + number2);
        if (val == perimeter) {
            correctQuestions++;
            Toast.makeText(this, "The answer is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The answer is incorrect ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        findViewById(R.id.showsolbutton).setEnabled(true);

        // Display text
        youTextView.setText(String.valueOf(correctQuestions) + " correct out of " + String.valueOf(totalQuestion));
    }
}
```

Comment: when i type in my textview, ID an error is coming up "cannot resolve symbol myscore"

Comment: Thanks a lot i got it fixed !!

Comment: Glad to hear that. If the answer was helpful don't forget to vote up or mark as answer. Cheers!